# How do I do analysis where I can tell what attributes made x times likely to be something?

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

Say 300 students graduated.

Some got jobs and some didn't in 1 year.

Some became CEOS.

Now I've a table with all their attributes that could be relevant.

First name | age | family income | gender | race | major | political views | opinion about lottery tickets | weight | night owl or morning bird | smartphone type | etc...

given all attributes how can i mathematically find out or prove that people with x attribute true were more likely to get a job than people who had it false.

also what is this called so i can learn this stuff. I can guess something to do with probability.

Comment: You should consider asking this question in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). What this stuff is called is Statistics / Machine Learning / Data Science (they are not the same thing but they intersect a lot).